# requested url solr/update/extract not available on this server

Tags: solr

I am working on Solr 4.2 on Windows 7.
I am trying to index pdf files.I referred Solr Cookbook 4.
Tomcat is using 8080 port number.
I get this error:requested url solr/update/extract not available on this server

There is no entry in log files.
Please help.

Comment: I use this url: curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract/literal.id=1?commit=true" -F"myfile=@solr.pdf"

Comment: Is the context root solr when deployed to Tomcat ?? what is the war file names ?? also in the solrconfig.xml file do you have the entry <requestHandler name="/update/extract"  ???

Comment: I get the solr admin page.War file is solr folder.I did define the request handler update/extract also my other queries like select is working fine.

Comment: If you have more then one core defined in SolR you need to specify the core name in the URL when you do the test: 
curl "http://localhost:8080/solr/CORENAME/update/extract?literal.id=1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@test.pdf"